# Create multiple tables in one statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to do multiple queries on Oracle, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE  AS
   (SELECT (ID, NOMBRECLIENTE, NIT_CLIENTE,SEXO,EDAD,TELEFONO,DIR_CLIENTE)
    FROM RESTAURANT)

CREATE TABLE COMPRAS  AS
   (SELECT (ID, NOMBRECLIENTE, NIT_CLIENTE,SEXO,EDAD,TELEFONO,DIR_CLIENTE)
    FROM RESTAURANT)

CREATE TABLE HORARIO  AS
   (SELECT (ID, NOMBRECLIENTE, NIT_CLIENTE,SEXO,EDAD,TELEFONO,DIR_CLIENTE)
    FROM RESTAURANT)
```

but in one query sentence.

Comment: two queries look the same

Comment: This is one query run twice. In any case, you can't run multiple CREATE queries as one query - they're all separate.

Comment: What is the original task?

Comment: it's just an example, let's say that are diferents, but i want to run multiple querys like this just in one query, how can i do that?

Comment: Some things can't be done in one _statement_  -`CREATE TABLE` is one of them.  If you have a _specific_ example versus a hypothetical one, you'll get a better answer.  You can, however put multiple _statements_ into one _batch_.

Comment: @DStanley how can i do that?, multiple statements in one batch? i try,with ";" at the end of each one, and desn't work ...

Comment: Union all might work. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/38b0b/1. Not sure what you are after.

Comment: What doe you mean "it doesn't work"? How are you executing the batch?  Are you trying to create the same table 3 times?

Comment: @DStanley no, i'm not trying to create 3 times the same, i change the values.

Comment: **PLEASE VOTE TO RE-OPEN.  The code is very close to running, it's pretty clear what he's asking now.**

Answer (score 3):

Your code is very close to working, just add a [`CREATE SCHEMA`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_6014.htm#SQLRF01313):

```
CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION JHELLER --schema name must be hard-coded
    CREATE TABLE CLIENTE  AS
       (SELECT ID, NOMBRECLIENTE, NIT_CLIENTE,SEXO,EDAD,TELEFONO,DIR_CLIENTE
        FROM RESTAURANT)
    CREATE TABLE COMPRAS  AS
       (SELECT ID, NOMBRECLIENTE, NIT_CLIENTE,SEXO,EDAD,TELEFONO,DIR_CLIENTE
        FROM RESTAURANT)
    CREATE TABLE HORARIO  AS
       (SELECT ID, NOMBRECLIENTE, NIT_CLIENTE,SEXO,EDAD,TELEFONO,DIR_CLIENTE
        FROM RESTAURANT);
```

Combining statements is a normally a great way to improve performance and clarity.  But in this case it's probably better to leave each `CREATE TABLE` as a separate statement.

Comment: thank you!, but what i need is to create multiple tables, populating this one, with other tables!, just in one query sentence. Update: also!, your answer give me ideas... Thank you!...

Comment: +1 . . . I didn't know that.  Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE  AS
   SELECT ID, NOMBRECLIENTE, NIT_CLIENTE,SEXO,EDAD,TELEFONO,DIR_CLIENTE
   FROM RESTAURANT
   union all
   SELECT ID, NOMBRECLIENTE, NIT_CLIENTE,SEXO,EDAD,TELEFONO,DIR_CLIENTE
   FROM RESTAURANT
   union all
   SELECT ID, NOMBRECLIENTE, NIT_CLIENTE,SEXO,EDAD,TELEFONO,DIR_CLIENTE
   FROM RESTAURANT;
```

Comment: thank you,well i need to create 3 tables diferent names, just in one query

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's unusual but possible to create three tables in a single query, see my answer below.  Can you use your new gold badge power to re-open this question?